# Sum of $f(x)$ and $f(\frac{1}{x})$ for a monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, monotone-functions

I came across this question from a competitive exam:

$\textbf{Problem: }$Given $f:[\frac{1}{2},2]\to\mathbb{R}$ a strictly increasing function, define $g:[1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})$. Does there exist a suitable $f$ for which there is a partition $P$ of $[1,2]$ such that $U(P,g)=L(P,g)$? Here, $U(P,g)$ and $L(P,g)$ are the upper and lower Riemann sums respectively.

I could figure this out and the answer is $\textbf{Yes}$. One can take $f(x)=\log x$, $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$, etc. So this is alright.

I thought of making $g$ to be a constant function to construct the above examples. While trying to come up with these examples, I made some rough graphs that satisfied the hypotheses of the problem and observed something that I want to ask about. Later, I drew several graphs in Desmos as well and observed the same thing. My question is, is the following true?

$\textbf{Question:}$ For $a>1$, given $f:[\frac{1}{a},a]\to\mathbb{R}$ a monotonic function, define $g:[1,a]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})$. Is $g$ always non-decreasing?

I feel it is true. But I could not prove it. Neither could I construct a counterexample. Any hints to prove/disprove the above statement are appreciated.

If the above result is true, then the only possible candidates for $g$ in the above original problem can be constants, right? That is why I got interested in this.

$\textbf{Please note:}$ I am not assuming any continuity conditions anywhere. Just monotonicity.

Comment: $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$ and $a=2$. If I understood the question right this is a counterexample

Comment: Take even $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x} + 5$. $f(x) > 0$ over $[\frac{1}{2}, 2]$, $|f(x)| = f(x)$, and $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing, so if you add any one of these conditions it will still yield at least one counterexample.

Comment: @RyanShesler Ah, you're right. The negative numbers do the trick. Thanks. But what if I say, $g$ is always at least monotonic? Is that true?

Comment: $g(x)$ in the counterexample I provided is still monotonic so no. However, all the counterexamples I could find have their derivatives of $g(x)$ equal to $0$ at $x=1$, which I think violates strict monotonicity? That may be something worth looking into as a necessary condition

Comment: @RyanShesler But I am considering $g$ only in the interval $[1,a]$. In that interval, it is always monotonic, no?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. Yes, I think you can prove using inequalities that if $f(x)$ is monotonic, so is $g(x)$, but I have not looked into that yet. What I thought you were asking is if saying $g(x)$ is monotonic is a sufficient condition for your question to hold, to which I provided the former response.

Comment: @RyanShesler But I was unable to prove monotonicity by using inequalities. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109446/discussion-between-ryan-shesler-and-whysee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = -x$ and $a=2$ is a counterexample to the question. Moreover, $g(x)$ is not necessarily monotonic if $f(x)$ is. This is due to the counterexample $f(x) = x^2-4.5x+3.5$ and $a=2$. $f(x)$ is monotonic but $g(x)$ switches from decreasing to increasing at around $1.64$, which is a root of multiplicity $1$ of $g'(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! This is great!